# spyder: Running without the SUID sandbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I install spyder by:

```
sudo pip3 install spyder
```

When I run it:

```
~$ spyder
```

It shows the following error:

```
    [1016/190710:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! 
See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to fix this error? My ubuntu version is 16.10